# Easily run a BigQuery query from the commandline and download the results?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm doing some data processing with BigQuery and would like to use the output of some queries as input into the next stage of a data processing pipeline, ideally allowing me to do something like this:

```
bigquery $QUERY | ./process.sh
```

I'm able to achieve something similar by doing this currently:

```
bq --nosync query --max_rows 100000000 --use_cache --batch --use_legacy_sql=false $QUERY

bq wait $JOBID

bq --format csv head -j $JOBID --max_rows 100000000 | ./process.sh
```

But I'm not sure if downloading all of the data (tens of millions of rows) with `head` is less efficient than instead writing the results to a table, and then exporting that to google storage, and then downloading it? Is there any existing tools that abstract all of this away for me, and just let me run a query and then send/download the full output for me?

Comment: This simply isn't going to scale. What is your script doing with that data? BigQuery is designed for analytics and aggregation, and not pulling tens of millions of rows over the wire and then into a bash script.

Comment: For the purposes of this question what the script does doesn't really matter, and I actually have multiple pipelines in which the processing step does various different things. 

I am indeed using BigQuery for analytics and aggregation, but I need to process the data in a simple way. It's trivial with AWS RedShift, which I'm migrating over from. It seems doable with BigQuery either with my `head` example or by downloading from GCS, but I'm like to find a command that abstracts that away from me.

Comment: What about using a Cloud Dataflow pipeline instead? Or do you have to stay in bash?

Answer (score 0):

Using `head` you may reach API quota limits and very poor performance for that much data as it is not what it is intended for. Also note that setting [max_rows above the limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#paging-through-list-results) will only return the limit. Your idea to export the destination table is the right way to go. 
You can find more information on exporting [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) and on downloading from [gcs here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-tofrom-subdirectories-distributing-transfers-across-machines).

```
bq extract --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare' gs://example-bucket/shakespeare.json


gsutil cp -r gs://example-bucket/shakespeare.json local_dir
```

Comment: What quota? Can you give a command line example of exporting and then downloading data?

Comment: Actually the only quota on this call is the standard API qps quota: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#apirequests. But performance will definitely suffer using 'head' especially as you get further down the table. Setting max_rows to 100000000 won't work as that is above the max_rows limit of 100k, so it will just return 100k: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#paging-through-list-results. I'll update the answer to include examples.

Comment: No it definitely works - I'm getting over 5 million results this way. The query command max a max limit of 10k, but the head command has no maximum.

Comment: Ah, you're right - the backend has that limit but the command line client pages the results for you. So it is still making many requests but then combining it before returning the results.